# Posting from one RequestHandler to another in App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

**Goal:** Using app engine's basic webapp framework I want to create a new request, with post data, to send to another RequestHandler.  Something like `pageGenerator.post({'message':'the message','datum1':datum1,...})`...

**Problem Description:** One request handler, call it `pageGenerator`, creates a page with a form on it. When the user submits the form, the post goes to a different handler: `dataProcessor`. If `dataProcessor` finds some problem with the submitted data it would send the submitted data plus an Error Message to 'pageGenerator`'s post method, and pageGenerator would serve up the page with the error message.

How do I pass data (and control) back and forth like this? I would like `pageGenerator` to be able to get the data with `self.request.get('message')`.

Comment: Is there a reason dataProcessor needs to be a RequestHandler?  Wouldn't it be easier if it was just some code that pageGenerator calls internally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're over-complicating things. Consider just having a common method to show the form that can be invoked in different circumstances:

```
class FormHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):
    self.show_form()

  def post(self):
    if form_is_valid():
      handle_success()
    else:
      self.show_form({'feedback':'Validation failed'})

  def show_form(self, vals={}):
    vals['field1'] = self.request.get('field1')
    vals['field2'] = self.request.get('field2')
    html = template.render('form.html', vals)
    self.response.out.write(html)
```

If you really need "display form" and "process form" to be in different handler classes, you can accomplish the same thing by defining `show_form()` in a common parent class.

Comment: The form is a comment box that relies on post data to determine what is being commented on (and the key of the comment if this is an edit). Because submitting the form is also a post action I created a different handler to receive the request. The validation function is in the second handler and wants to send the user back to the first, but needs to include the submitted data and the key of the object being commented on.

Comment: @Hank None of which makes this answer less valid - you can still call a common method (on a base class) or function that both handlers use for the functionality. This is a much simpler and more portable approach.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll work on this. I had trouble with using inheritance in my app once before, but I just started messing around with it and it seems to be working.